# Console returning baddata

Tags: angularjs

I cannot figure out why this http post is returning bad data in console :-

```
var dataObj = {"id": 21};

$http.post('http://localhost:9099/GetItems', dataObj).then(function(response) {
   var size = response.data.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var list = response.data.split(",");
        for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
             var elem = angular.element("#" + s);
             elem.style.visible = "block";
        }
   }

});
```

I changed `GetItems` to a different api - this had no problem.

Comment: sounds like a back-end problem, where is the data coming from?

Comment: what data type is expected on server side ? try passing the same eg: `application/json`  and let us know

Comment: I tested backend with postman rest client using the same json as body, no problems

Comment: Please add that postman response with dummy data to understand the issue better.

Comment: I found the problem, I returning the string directly instead of making it a json

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get data from back end belongs to the id.

To get items use `get` instead of `post`

Like `$http.get('http://localhost:9099/GetItems' + id)`